# How to correctly pass return of one method to another in JSON-RPC in one request?

Tags: api-design, json-rpc

I'm making typical JSON-RPC API (based on [json-rpc Python library](https://github.com/pavlov99/json-rpc)) for the serverless E-Commerce site.

I want to register users when they are ordering something. And I'd like to do this in one request (because I'm using service like AWS Lambda).
Currently I think that I may just add a merged method like Register + Order = RegisterAndOrder. But it may look ugly because JSON-RPC has support for batch requests.
As I know you can't just pass return of one method to another.

Are there any other ways that I don't know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found proper solution. I need to add variable like context, that will be shared for all batch functions.
If user calls register, this function will return some variables and add key-value pair to the context variable.
Function order will check this key-pair. If its exists, the function will run OK. Otherwise, it will throw an exception.

I forked JSON-RPC python library to [JSON-RPC-Stateful](https://pypi.org/project/json-rpc-stateful).